# Insert the size of Array Dynamically and keep the old values in array

Tags: java, arrays, swing

Is that possible that I can increase the size of Array dynamically and keep the old value in the Array. We don't know the size of array as user is keep inserting the value and we have to change the array length after every input. So I will appreciate if somebody has better alternative then what I am trying to achieve.

```
private static String[] hotelName;
private static int lent=1;

public FiletoArray() 
{
     hotelName=new String[lent];
     initComponents();
}

private void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
      // TODO add your handling code here:
      insertHotel(this.jTextField1.getText());
      this.jLabel3.setText("" + lent);
      lent=lent+1;
      for(int a=0;a<lent;a++)
      {
          this.jTextArea1.setText(hotelName[a] + "\n");
      }
}                                        

public static void insertHotel(String hotelValue)
{ 
       hotelName[lent-1]=hotelValue;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) if possible, it will dynamically grow to fit its data. If you need to use an array, then you'll need to allocate a new (larger) array, and then use [System.arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) to copy over the old array's contents.